# Is it possible to spawn an own Windows10 window inside the Unity HoloLens applications realworld

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to create a Unity Program for HoloLens. I am used to spawn a **3D window** inside the projected world. Is it possible to spawn windows like the "Settings" window from the HoloLens Windows10 **inside** my application?

Or is it possible to spawn another program inside the app?

Or what would be the best way to spawn a 3D window which contains **UI-elements** like ScrollViews, Text, Buttons and Images?

Comment: Surely much much simpler to use Unity UI to fake any look you need, than to worry about expensive and complicated window grabbing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can't use the code/design of those windows directly in your app, but you can make your own to look similar.  Here's an [older example](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/htk_release/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/UX/Readme/README_BoundingBoxGizmoExample.md) of a hololens UI that has been made to look similar to the system ones.

2) It is not currently possible to spawn another program inside a UWP app, sorry.

3) The best (and easiest to learn) way is using the [built in UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui) classes that Unity provides.  After following those tutorials, making it work in hololens will be straightforward.

Comment: A friend told me that you cannot place Canvas in the world without following the camera because it is made for onscreen UI elements like a menu. Is this correct?

Comment: @I'maCar Look up "world space canvas."